# Python fails silently when moving code in another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

I'm pretty new to python and I have a strange issue which I can't manage to understand by my own, I'm sure it's stupid but I can see what it is and never encountered before, even having wiring several python scripts with lots of subfiles

For the record I'm coding and launching my script with Spyder (Python 3.6 version) on Windows but I set #!/usr/lib/python2.7/ at the beginning of each file

My main script is a big file and I wanted to refactor it by externalising code in some other files

The main is like that :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    configuration = Conf.loadConf(os.path.join(scriptDir,confFile))
    print(configuration)    
    loadFavs(configuration,bioses,setDict)
```

When loadFavs is in main script everything works fine

As soon as I move it in fav.py file at same level than my main script adding `import fav` and modifying fav.loadFavs(configuration,bioses,setDict) it stops working and Spyder just says nothing without any reason :

```
In [1]: runfile('C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade/fav.py', wdir='C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade')

In [2] runfile('C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade/fav.py', wdir='C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade')
```

The first line `configuration = Conf.loadConf(os.path.join(scriptDir,confFile))` should print things on screen and it doesn't even show

As soon as I put back the code in main script my code works again

It happens with several different part of the script I tried to put in different files

I'm at a  loss here, what I checked :

- having at the beginning of each file

  #!/usr/lib/python2.7/

  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
- always end the script on an empty line
- creating each file within Spyder and not outside

I don't thing the code I move is the issue has it works fine in main script and I had the issue with several pieces of code but here it is :

```
def parseSetFile(setFile, setDict) :
    file = open(setFile,'r')
    genre = None
    # Parse iniFile in iniFile dir    
    for line in file.readlines() :
        line = line.rstrip('\n\r ')
        if (line.startswith('[') and not line == '[FOLDER_SETTINGS]' and not line == '[ROOT_FOLDER]') :            
            genre = line
            if genre not in setDict :                
                setDict[genre] = []
        else :
            if (genre is not None and not line == '' ) :
                setDict[genre].append(line)

def loadFavs(configuration, bioses, setDict) :
    print("Load favs small set")
    parseSetFile(os.path.join(configuration['scriptDir'],dataDir,smallSetFile),setDict)
    print("Load favs big set")
    parseSetFile(os.path.join(configuration['scriptDir'],dataDir,bigSetFile),setDict)

    print('Nb Genre : %s' %len(setDict))    
    sumGames = 0
    for key in setDict.keys() :
        # print(key)
        # print(setDict[key])
        sumGames = sumGames + len(setDict[key])

    print('Nb Games : %s' %sumGames)
    print('Nb Bios : %s' %len(bioses))
```

Comment: Not familiar with Spyder but a directory name is not a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: The shebang will hbe ignored by python/spyder and the shebang in general only works on Linux-like systems. This should not be the problem. You should prefer `/usr/bin/env python` though.

Comment: Can you move the file, insert `import fav` and run `print(dir(fav))` in the main file? This should print the functions defined in the `fav` module. This should help for debugging this issue.

Comment: @meisterluk this is what I get, everything is defined it seems : ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'bigSetFile', 'dataDir', 'loadFavs', 'os', 'parseSetFile', 'smallSetFile']

Comment: OK i'm effectively massively stupid : In [1]: runfile('C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade/fav.py', wdir='C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade'), I'm launching my fav.py subscript not the main one, and off course it doesn't have any main ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i'm effectively massively stupid :

`In [1]: runfile('C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade/fav.py', wdir='C:/DevZone/workspaceFX/scripts4recalbox/BestArcade')`

I'm launching my fav.py subscript not the main one, and off course it doesn't have any main ......